# How can I pull the second (or third or fourth) ten entries from a Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I know I could use pagination gems to accomplish a task like this, but I want to better understand some rails native methods of doing so.

Let's say I want the first entries in a model, I could do:

```
 Model.order("created_at ASC").limit(10)
```

But I want to, say, find the second or third or fourth ten entries. How would I do that?

```
 Model.order("created_at ASC").#take the second ten or something
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You many want to use the `offset` method:

```
Client.limit(5).offset(30)
```

returns 5 items starting from 31st item.